# How to compare cells of one column for selected rows?

Tags: c#

Hi everyone please i need you're help if it's possible:
i have a DGV with 8 columns i want to compare all cells of second column "Fournisseur" whene rows are selected.

- image1: selected rows have the same value of second column "Tramauto"="Tramauto"
- image2: selected rows have differents values of sec column 1row "Tramauto"= 3row "Tramauto" but 2row different "Sonasid"

[image: If=True]

[image: If=False]

```
private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      foreach (DataGridViewRow row in commandeDataGridView.SelectedRows)
            {
                 if(//selected rows have the same value of second column)
                    {do function}

               else
            {

                string message = "shoose the same Fournisseur";
                string title = "Error";
                MessageBox.Show(message,title);
            }
```

Thank you so much for you're help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
List<string> allCol2Values = commandeDataGridView.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(r => r.Cells[1].Value?.ToString())
    .ToList();
string first = allCol2Values.FirstOrDefault();
bool allSame = allCol2Values.Skip(1).All(s => s == first);
```

Comment: Hi Mr Tim i'm a beginner please can you tell me where i should put this code because i have 2 conditions so i think i should use IF and ELSE and thank you so much.

Comment: @walid: You wanted to know how to determine the condition of the `if`. My variable `allSame` is the answer to that. So: `if(allSame) {do this} else {do that}`